# inter orbital link: frequency band

Tags: communication-satellite

In technical documentation, it is discussed inter-satellite links. As I understood, under inter-satellite link they mean a link between satellites allocated on the same orbit, LEO to LEO, MEO to MEO, and GEO to GEO.

But there is a link between satellites like LEO and GEO, LEO or MEO for example.

Can I use the same frequency for the communication links?